# background invalid property

Tags: css, background-image

The page only accepts colors in the backgroud, images not

```
  background: url (img/fondo-ingresar.jpg);
```

I even tried to put it in the HTML but still the same error of **"Invalid Property Value"**

Comment: This is confusing. Can you clarify what it is that you are asking?

Comment: You need to remove the space between `url` and `(img...`. I've voted to close this as a *simple typographical error*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space and it works

```
 background: url(img/fondo-ingresar.jpg);
```

`background` property is the resume of multiple properties, and you can define values space separated:

```
 background: #fff center center no-repeat url(url.jpg);
```

If you put an space between `url` and `()` it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
background: url("img/fondo-ingresar.jpg");
```

Remove the space between url and parenthesis and put path into quotes.

P.S. You could also try to load it with `background-image` property:

```
background-image: url("img/fondo-ingresar.jpg");
```

Comment: The path doesn't have to be in quotes.

Comment: Yeah, but that does not mean it can't be in quotes. :)

Personally I'm always putting it in quotes. It happened to me too many times that path without quotes caused trouble.

Comment: If paths without quotes caused trouble, it's because you have bad names in files (spaces in them). So you workaround a problem, but you don't fix it.